# migrate module:not getting cck fields

Tags: drupal, migration

i m trying to migrate a content type "product" from another database system..
The migrate module is helping me a lot with it..
i M able to map the basic node properties such as title description and others..but not getting the cck field such as price..

can ne1 help me out with how to map cck fields..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help but i figured it out..dere s a module migrate_extras providing import features with cck fields and a few others also..it works..:)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the Migrate module yet, but have been meaning to give it a spin.  But as far as migrating CCK fields and quite a few other really useful things, I find the Features module to be a godsend.  And it's really simple and easy to use! http://drupal.org/project/features

If that isn't appropriate for you, what about just exporting/importing the content type?  (After enabling that module function)